# MacVim always force tabs

Tags: macvim

I've noticed that if I open too many files on my MacVim simultaneously, i.e., select all files in Finder and drag to MacVim, it takes some of the files and places them in a split window rather than giving them their own tabs.

Is there a way to disable this so that every file is always opened in its own tab? I've already selected the `with a tab for each file` option in the `Open files from applications` Preferences.

The interesting thing is if I open each file one by one, then they do always get their own tab. The problem occurs when I do a bulk open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is still an issue so I've posted this as a [Github issue](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/261).

UPDATE: looks like you can solve this by setting `tabpagemax` to a higher value in your vim config!